# How to add conditional data from a datatable into another datatable. [error: " no row at position 0] . C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, rows, dbf

I am new to programming and got this job to create a tool to convert .DBF table into a .csv file.

so here is the scenario; 
The dbf table 'Poles' contain four fields 'pole_id', 'guy_hoa_1', 'guy_hoa_2','guy_hoa_3' and 'guy_hoa_4'. 
And the final csv file should show the value in two columns only:'PoleId' and 'HOA' respectively, where PoleID will be == pole_id and HOA= guy_hoa_1 + '|' +guy_hoa_2+'|' +guy_hoa_3 +'|'+ guy_hoa_4.

for example, the Poles table will have data like;
[Sample data of Poles table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnyZL.png)

And, the ouput csv file should show data as follows;

[Sample Output CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i5Mt.png)

*The pole_id is the main field and based on it the values of other fields will be selected.

So far I managed to write following code:

enter code here

```
enter code here
            string str = textBox1.Text;
            string path = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = '" + path + "';Extended Properties=dBase IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = conn;
            connection.Open();
            CheckConnectionLabel.Text = "Connected Successfully";



            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT pole_id, guy_hoa_1, guy_hoa_2,guy_hoa_3,guy_hoa_4 FROM poles" + ".dbf", connection);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);


         DataTable dt1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(r=> r.Field<string>("pole_id")!= null)
                        .Where(r=> r.Field<string>("pole_id")!=" ")
                        .CopyToDataTable();




         DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
         dtTemp.Columns.Add("PoleId", typeof(String)); 
         dtTemp.Columns.Add("HOA", typeof(string));
         string x = string.Empty;



        for (int i=0;i< dt1.Rows.Count;i++)
        {

            if(dt1.Rows[i]["pole_id"]!= null || dt1.Rows[i]["pole_id"].ToString()!= "")

          {

              if(dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_1"]!=null && dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_1"].ToString()!="")

                { 

                     x =dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_1"].ToString();
                }

             if(dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_2"]!= null && dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_2"].ToString()!="")

               {
                      x = x + "|" + dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_2"].ToString();
               }


            if(dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_3"]!=null && dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_3"].ToString()!= "")
              {
                       x = x + "|" + dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_3"].ToString();
              }

             if(dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_4"]!=null && dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_4"].ToString()!= "")
             {
                       x = x + "|" + dt1.Rows[i]["guy_hoa_4"].ToString();
             }


           dtTemp.Rows[i]["PoleId"] = dt1.Rows[i]["poles_id"].ToString();
           dtTemp.Rows[i]["HOA"] = x ;

          }

          }

       connection.Close();


       dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTemp;



       }
        catch (Exception ex)
              {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
               }
 }


enter code here
```

So, through above code I am connected to the dbf table and collected required data in 'dt' table. Then I  filtered the data by removing the rows where pole_id was blank/null and put it in another 'dt1' table. Now my purpose was to check the conditions in dt1 table and then fill rows in dtTemp table which would later display the data in datagridview.

The Code is fetching the value of x till last IF statement correctly however nothing is getting filled up in dtTemp datatable and then showing this error.

Please help me and let me know where I am wrong... many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution as follows;

```
enter code here
                    object y = dt1.Rows[i]["pole_id"].ToString();
                    dtTemp.NewRow();
                    dtTemp.Rows.Add(y ,x);
```